# Currency formatting with c++

Tags: c++, formatting, currency

Is there an obvious way to perform currency formatting in C++ ?

For example: 1978879 would become 1'978'879

Thanks

Comment: What he did is the equivalent for that using German formatting rules.

Comment: Take a look at the `<locale>` header and documentation.

Comment: @Sven that is not German formatting. 1.978.879,00 is German

Comment: @RedX Hmm, I though Germans did that too. Oh well, I could be wrong. In any case, they're the thousands separators in some locale or other. :) And I'm Dutch, what you did is what we do too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

```
int value = 1978879;
std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

Locales are responsible for formatting. Any stream can be imbued with a locale; by default they use the global locale, which by default is the "C" locale which doesn't use any thousands separators. By creating a locale instance with the empty string as the parameter we use the user's locale, which in your case will likely be Swiss.

You can also specify an explicit locale name, but the names are different depending on your platform (Linux/Windows), and not all systems support all locales.

If you want to get a string, the easiest way is probably to use a stringstream (from the `<sstream>` header):

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream.imbue(std::locale(""));
stream << value;
std::string stringValue = stream.str();
```

Though you can also use the locale's facets directly, but that's more complicated.

You could also set the global locale, which will be used by all streams (unless they're specifically imbued with a different locale):

```
std::locale::global(std::local(""));
```

Comment: When you have finished developing and are ready to release the first thing you should do is add `std::locale::global(std::local(""));` as the first statement is main. Then test again.

Comment: After setting the locale, you could use `cout << put_money( value )` to make sure that the correct formatting for currency is used. This does assume that `value` is given in the smallest units of the currency, e.g. cents or rappen, so you may want to multiply `value` by 100.

Comment: Thanks andrew, that put my on the right track to a solution for a similar problem. Currency <> Number and I really needed the monetary formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the standard C++ localization library. It's not that straightforward but you can probably achieve that through the [num_get](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/num-get.html)/[numpunct](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/numpunct.html) facets.

Comment: Actually its trivial to do. See above.